# Creating multi switches dynamically using React-switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a list of data, which i displayed in the frontend using map function. Each data will have an switch button. If a user clicks on a particular, it will display an description regarding the data below. Now, if i use static data. it switch working properly. But all get selected at the same time. I want only the particular one to get select, when i click the particular one. I am using react-switch library for the switch. Below is my code, Pleasse check and let me know, how cal I achieve that.

```
/***Parent Component***/

import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReqLists from "./ReqLists";

class Requirements extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      reqs: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Application",
          details: "Do you require an application from volunteers?"
        },
        { id: 1, name: "Screening Questions", details: "", description: "Dummy content" },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Recurring commitment",
          details:
            "Does this opportunity require a recurring commitment from volunteers?", description: "Dummy content"
        },
        { id: 3, name: "Documents for volunteers to upload ", details: "", description: "Dummy content" },
        { id: 4, name: "Waiver & Release of Liability Forms", details: "", description: "Dummy content"  },
        { id: 5, name: "Parental Consent & Medical Form", details: "", description: "Dummy content"  },
        { id: 6, name: "Age", details: "", description: "Dummy content"  },
        { id: 7, name: "Certifications", details: "", description: "Dummy content"  },
        { id: 8, name: "Languages", details: "", description: "Dummy content"  },
        { id: 9, name: "Skils", details: "", description: "Dummy content"  },
        { id: 10, name: "Additional Requirements", details: "", description: "Dummy content"  },
        { id: 11, name: "Additional Details", details: "", description: "Dummy content"  }
      ],
      checked: 0
    };
  }
  handleChange = id => {
    const checked = this.state.checked;
    checked[id] = checked.hasOwnProperty(id) ? !checked[id] : true;
    this.setState({ checked });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <ReqLists
          lists={this.state.reqs}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          checked={this.state.checked}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Requirements;

/***Child Component***/

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import Switch from "react-switch";
class ReqLists extends Component {
  render() {
    const { lists, classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.reqWrapper}>
        {lists &&
          lists.map(list => {
            return (
              <div className={classes.reqCover} key={list.id}>
                <div className={classes.reqDetails}>
                  <Typography className={classes.reqListName}>
                    {list.name}
                    <span className={classes.reqListDetails}>
                      {list.details}
                    </span>
                  </Typography>
                  <Switch
                    className={classes.reqSwitch}
                    onChange={() => this.props.onChange(list.id)}
                    checked={this.props.checked === list.id}
                    offColor="#cacaca"
                    onColor="#2299e9"
                    uncheckedIcon={
                      <div className={classes.checkedIcon}>NO</div>
                    }
                    checkedIcon={<div className={classes.checkedIcon}>YES</div>}
                    height={17}
                    width={35}
                  />
                </div>
                {this.props.checked === list.id ? (
                  <div>
                    {list.description}
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ReqLists);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your handleChange method with this:** All you need to check if the selected id is not equals to checked id update checked state.

```
 handleChange = id => {
    let selectedItemIndex = this.state.reqs.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
    if (selectedItemIndex !== this.state.checked) {
     this.setState({checked: selectedItemIndex});
    }else{
 this.setState({checked: null});
}
  };
```

Comment: @JeyanthKanagaraj Happy to help! Kindly upvote to support.

Comment: Now, I can able to select only one in the entire list. If, I want to select more than one in the list. How can i do that?

Comment: for that, you can have checked flag in each of your object  of reqs. and change its state on click.

Comment: I couldn't make that work. Can you show that to me in the above code